# Android - how to structure new Activity class?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I have a home page activity that I got from an example, which works fine.  Now I am trying to make it have a button that makes the app go to the next screen.

So I added a second activity to the application manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name=".AddProblemActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

But I wonder if it is supposed to have these two lines:

```
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

It seems that MAIN is saying that there should be a main() function. But isn't that only supposed to exist on the home page?

Here is the full stack trace:

```
02-20 10:17:04.408: D/gralloc_goldfish(646): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
02-20 10:18:58.655: D/AndroidRuntime(646): Shutting down VM
02-20 10:18:58.665: W/dalvikvm(646): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
02-20 10:18:58.745: E/AndroidRuntime(646): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-20 10:18:58.745: E/AndroidRuntime(646): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.problemio/com.problemio.AddProblemActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-20 10:18:58.745: E/AndroidRuntime(646):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
02-20 10:18:58.745: E/AndroidRuntime(646):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
02-20 10:18:58.745: E/AndroidRuntime(646):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
02-20 10:18:58.745: E/AndroidRuntime(646):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
02-20 10:18:58.745: E/AndroidRuntime(646):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-20 10:18:58.745: E/AndroidRuntime(646):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-20 10:18:58.745: E/AndroidRuntime(646):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
02-20 10:18:58.745: E/AndroidRuntime(646):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-20 10:18:58.745: E/AndroidRuntime(646):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-20 10:18:58.745: E/AndroidRuntime(646):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
02-20 10:18:58.745: E/AndroidRuntime(646):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
02-20 10:18:58.745: E/AndroidRuntime(646):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-20 10:18:58.745: E/AndroidRuntime(646): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-20 10:18:58.745: E/AndroidRuntime(646):  at com.problemio.AddProblemActivity.onCreate(AddProblemActivity.java:28)
02-20 10:18:58.745: E/AndroidRuntime(646):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
02-20 10:18:58.745: E/AndroidRuntime(646):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
02-20 10:18:58.745: E/AndroidRuntime(646):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
02-20 10:18:58.745: E/AndroidRuntime(646):  ... 11 more
```

This is the part of my onCreate from AddProblemActivity causes the error it seems:

```
    final EditText problemName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.problem_name);  
    String name = problemName.getText().toString(); // THIS LINE
```

Here is my xml for is problem_name from the Layout xml:

```
    <EditText  
        android:id="@+id/problem_name"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:hint="@string/problem_name"  
        android:inputType="textPersonName"  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">  
    </EditText>
```

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `problemName` is probably null. Check if it is and make sure that you have done setContentView with a layout that contains such an id.
If you do you could also try to clean the build environment if you use an IDE such as Eclipse or IntelliJ IDEA since they sometimes keep old generated R files.

You should not have this intent filter unless you want the second activity to show up on the home screen.

```
<activity
android:name=".AddProblemActivity"
android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

will do if you just want to be able to start the second activity (AddProblemActivity) from the first.

Have a look at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html to learn about Intents and Intent filters.

Comment: @Sabastian thanks! What about if you want to have an intent. On the second Activity? :)

Comment: You're welcome. I'm sorry, but I don't quite understand your question. You can have intent filters for multiple activities. If you need help with finding out why the crash occured you should post a full stack trace.

Comment: I just added the full stack trace to my original question. Also, I changed my manifest to the snippet that you gave in your answer.

Comment: Good. Your crash has most likely nothing to do with the intent filter. The problem is in on row 28 (in onCreate). Could you also paste what happens around there?

Comment: just added that snippet. Its the second line of      final EditText problemName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.problem_name);  
     String name = problemName.getText().toString();

Comment: and by the way, I get the runtime exception when I click a button on the home page of the simulator. And all my form fields still end up in the home page screen - so there must be something strange still going on with that.

Comment: That can only cause a nullpointer exception if the variable problemName is null or problemName.getText() is null, but getText() never returns null so it is problem name. I'll update the answer.

Comment: I also added the xml snippet from the XML file for the layout that makes the element.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7972/discussion-between-sebastian-olsson-and-genadinik)

Answer (score 1):

1. Change the category tag of the new activity to `android.intent.category.DEFAULT` instead of `android.intent.category.LAUNCHER`.
2. Change the name of the action to some other value e.g. `android.intent.action.AddProblemActivity`